# Change location of local maven repository in gradle

Tags: maven, gradle

`publishToMavenLocal` always publishes to either ~/.m2 or the path set for `<LocalRepository>` tag in `~/.m2/settings.xml`. However when I set the system property `maven.repo.local` it is ignored. Is there a way to override the location of the local maven repository when publishing using `gradle publishToMavenLocal`, other than settings.xml (I am looking for either project property or system property or environment variable).

Here is what I tried `gradle -Dmaven.repo.local=/home/skgupta/myrepo build pTML`

Please help

Comment: Something like that: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/gradle-goodness-use-our-local-maven.html ?

Comment: The `install` task is installing / deploying the artifact and its dependent jars as well to the repository location specified. The requirement is to just publish the artifact itself with pom file. Similar to what happens when we use `mavenLocal()`, except that I want location used by `mavenLocal()` to be controlled by gradle script.

Answer (score 4):

Your `-Dmaven.repo.local` approach is working on my Gradle v4.8.1, here is the rundown:

```
gradle --stop
export M2_HOME=/tmp/other_em_two
export M2_REPO=$M2_HOME/repository
mkdir -p $M2_REPO
tree $M2_REPO
gradle -Dmaven.repo.local=$M2_REPO pTML
tree $M2_REPO
```

Will show published files.